# Is it possible to continuously scrape data using Firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase

I'm trying to create an IOS app and a large part of it is scraping data from a website every 10 or so minutes in order to know whether or not to send push notifications to the user. Is this possible to do? (For example, say every 10 minutes I needed to scrape Apple.com and then possibly send a notification to the user based on that data.) If this is possible, how would I integrate this Firebase functionality into Swift?

Comment: You can schedule Firebase functions: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions But, that's done on the server side, so the question of `how would I integrate this Firebase functionality into Swift` doesn't quite make sense here.

Comment: Well I'd want to send a notification only if a certain condition of what I'm collecting is met, which I assume would be in swift and not in firebase. Is this not possible then?

Comment: Push notifications are sent from the server and most of the time, triggered from there as well.

Comment: I'd need like an if statement and such. So if it's from the server is this not possible then? Sorry I'm new to all of this

Comment: When your app is terminated (not running in the background) you will also be severely limited with what the app can do. https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-run-code-when-your-app-is-terminated A scheduled firebase function or cron job would be the most reliable way to accomplish this. Also watch this video and playlist it shows how push notifications commonly work with firebase: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sioEY4tWmLI&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLkuHRCtHTpi6JYHka8oHLft